# Can I find the URL from which pip installs packages

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to retrieve the URL of package installed by pip?

For example, I want  the URL of Cython 0.29.19 for arm64 installed by `pip3 install Cython==0.29.19`

Comment: have you tried `pip show package`?

Answer (score -2):

You can search the packages on https://pypi.org. 
pip installs packages from there.

You can manually download the file and load it to your local Python installation using pip.

Here is the link for cython:
https://pypi.org/project/Cython/#files

Comment: @BennyK But there is the source distribution so most probably `pip` downloaded and compiled it. And no, there is no way to ask `pip` if it really did exactly that and from what URL it downloaded the source distribution.